# Nam is not working

Tags: apt, virtualbox, ns2

I installed Nam. with this command in terminal.

`sudo apt install nam`

when ever I run Nam in terminal with command `nam`. it is not showing GUI

but it is displaying [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqPgp.png).

I'm running in a virtual machine, and I installed ns2 it is working fine.

version-ubuntu 22.04 LtS

Comment: The picture shows me you are running Kali which is not Ubuntu and that is off topic on this site. You can ask the question on this other site https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Now i'm working in ubuntu not Kali linux. @David

Comment: Find that hard to believe your question still has a screen shot taken from Kali.

Comment: "I installed Nam" : How did you "install" `nam` ? ? ............ And please **edit** https://askubuntu.com/posts/1437666/edit your question to show text as {text lines}, not as an image https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text

Comment: i have edited it. now it there is you want to know i can tell it. @KnudLarsen

Comment: @David You're mistaken. He has a Kali VM. However, the Ubuntu VM is the active tab. The question reads as perfectly on topic here.

Comment: Read all the question and comments. He was running Kali when I said off topic. Then he said he changed it.

Comment: The package `nam` is currently corrupt (Low priority, was also corrupt years 2014 - 2019) ..... Valid packages https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ns-stop-couldn%27t-execute-nam-permission-denied-while-executing-exec-nam-4175524760/#2 ...... Example install: `sudo apt install Downloads/nam_1.15-10-ubuntu14_amd64.deb` ......... ( Tested OK with Ubuntu 22.04 )

Comment: Thank you informing I'll do this one @KnudLarsen

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read up on how `nam`, and related tools, actually work ;)

I'm not very familiar with those tools, but according to the [manual](https://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/doc/node609.html) you need to create a *trace file* that you then can hand over to `nam`:

> The first step to use nam is to produce the trace file. The trace file contains topology information, e.g., nodes, links, as well as packet traces. The detailed format is described in the section 49.1. Usually, the trace file is generated by ns.

The tool `ns` is in a separate package called `ns2`, so you may have to install that additionally.

According to [this tutorial](https://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/tutorial/nsscript1.html) you need to write a tcl script that describes the network you want to simulate. Then, you feed that script into `ns`, which generates a trace file. And then, you can feed that trace file into `nam`.

`ns`, `nam` and related tools are scientific tools which are often not very big on usability. So you need to write some code, learn some syntax and generally learn how the tools work. There's not much hand-holding offered, and the user is expected to read up on things on their own. Maybe you're more used to programs that are targeted to the general public, which often offer much more direct help and intuitive operation.

Comment: Simple, the package `nam` is corrupt  https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=nam;dist=unstable ......... → Please see other comments.

Answer (score 0):

The package `nam` is currently corrupt (Low priority, was also corrupt years 2014 - 2017)

Valid packages are https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ns-stop-couldn%27t-execute-nam-permission-denied-while-executing-exec-nam-4175524760/#2

Example install: `sudo apt install Downloads/nam_1.15-10-ubuntu14_amd64.deb`
Tested OK with Ubuntu 22.04 , Oct 27, 2022.